# Assembly program missing output

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm using x86 assembly code, intel format, with NASM on a linux VM.
The program is supposed to take two digits separated by space and print out the sum. I've looked at it with GDB and it works fine all the way through the entire thing, no errors or anything, except that it mutely declines to print the result. I'm new to assembly code so I don't really have a clue what I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT: Shortened the code to include only the more relevant bits. I think.

```
;Variables
section .bss
    digit       resb 1           

_start:
    ;Input Prompt
        ;Code block edited out.

    ;Reads 1st digit input, checks if the read operation was successfull,
    ;and stores the value in EAX.
    call _readDigit
    cmp edx,0
    jne _end
    mov eax,ecx

    ;Reads 2nd digit input, checks for read success,
    ;and stores the value in EBX.
    call _readDigit
    cmp edx,0
    jne _end
    mov ebx,ecx

    ;Sums EAX and EBX, stores result in ECX,
    ;and calls the write procedure.
    call _newLine
    add eax,ebx
    mov ecx,eax
    call _writeSum    

;Prints out the sum of two digits in the format 0X for values
;below 10, or 1X for values greater than 9.
_writeSum:
    push eax
    push ebx
    push ecx
    push edx

    mov [digit],ecx
    cmp ecx,9       ;Checks if sum > 9.
    jg _twoDigits

;Prints out 0 for the first digit in the result.
_oneDigit:
    mov ecx,48
    mov edx,1
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    int 80h

    mov ecx,[digit]
    jmp _lastDigit

;Prints out 1 for the first digit in the result,
;and subtracts 10 from ECX.
_twoDigits:
    mov ecx,49
    mov edx,1
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    int 80h

    mov ecx,[digit]
    sub ecx,10

;Converts ECX to ASCII and prints this as the
;second digit in the result.
_lastDigit:
    add ecx,'0'
    mov [digit],ecx

    mov ecx,[digit]
    mov edx,1
    mov ebx,STDOUT
    mov eax,SYS_WRITE
    int 80h

    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop ebx
    pop eax
    ret
```

Comment: Try running your code under strace (`strace ./a.out`) to see what args its actually passing to system calls.  BTW, your code is pretty long for a question, it's not really satisfying the minimal part of [mcve].  See also: the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for lots of good stuff.

Comment: For the start, try to explain what `digit resb 1` does... and what `mov ecx,[digit]` does (it's invalid combination). But that part accidentally may work (do `mov [digit],dword 0xDEADBEEF` at the very start of code to avoid working-by-luck). Then see how you use the `SYS_WRITE`, when you display "msg", it works, when you want to display sum, you use it in different way (and it doesn't work that way). Just look closely at arguments of those `int 80h` calls.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see right away is that you are moving the value you want printed out (48, 49, [digit]) directly into ecx.  SYS_WRITE expects ecx to contain a POINTER to a text string, not the value directly.

Second, you should consider manually populating the string (really, all inputs) with values you expect, so that you can be sure that the issue isn't with reading, etc.  Simply omitting the code that is called doesn't get you to a minimal error case, it just makes assumptions that are only true most of the time.